# Have webview selection and swipe at the same time

Tags: android-emulator

I have a webview containing some text. I need to be able to swipe on the `webview` and make text selection at the same time. The problem is after I have implemented the swipe overriding the `onTouchEvent` method, the other features of the `webview` seem to have freezed, links in the webview aren't clickable anymore, and the text selection (after `longClick`) doesn't work anymore, I need to make to implement the swipe and preserve the other features of the `webview`.

I tried to override the `longClick` click method as well and use the following method to implement text selection:

```
public void selectAndCopyText() {
    try {
        Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("emulateShiftHeld", null);
        m.invoke(MyWebView.this, null);
    } 
    catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(this);
    }
}
```

but it didn't work for when this method is called I only get the upper bar for `copy/ paste/ search/ websearch...` but no actual selection on the `webview` occur.

Comment: I was truly hoping for an answer, or a suggestion. If I have missed any details or have left some ambiguity in the question that are needed kindly let me know so I clarify.

Comment: did you found any solution for this?